# I am getting googleservices error on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-developers-console

This is my build.gradle code
   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the         google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

My build.gradle code is

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pandey.nidhiiot"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

and  my dependencies  are
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

Comment: show all content in `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of your app.gradle file instead of the beginning